# Git and ssh-agent on windows

Tags: git, ssh-agent

I have removed Git and reinstalled from here http://git-scm.com/download/win
on a windows 7 box.

The problem Im having is anytime ssh-agent starts up it keeps using CPU and fan on machine turns on e.g. running SourceTree starts it.

[image]

My work colleague has the same machine as me and does not have the issue. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: As in http://stackoverflow.com/a/26548170/6309?

Comment: No just CPU, disk is fine

Comment: Still, do you have an anti-virus which might interfere here?

Comment: Same problem here... seems like it has just started happening. I'm running windows 7 and windows defender is turned off. Any ideas on how I can troubleshoot this?